# iPhone img tag in local html file

Tags: iphone, html, webui

I have an image that is set to content and is in the root of the bundle. I have verified it is there in the simulator.

When I construct HTML to display in the UIWebView, this HTML fails to show the image:

Is there a relative path it should be in?

Note: I use the bundle as the base path in the call to show the html.

(I use MonoTouch)
NSUrl path = new NSUrl (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how MonoTouch plays with URL's, but since it's built atop NSUrl you probably still need to do something like this:

```
NSURL *myUrlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
```

You can't just use the plain NSURL constructor...